# Not able to approve tasks in Documentum D2

Tags: documentum, documentum-d2

In one of the workflows, task notification has been sent to an user's inbox. When the user tries to acquire the task, he is getting the error like `missing package for the current task of the workflow`.

Kindly provide me the suggestion on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

During the Workflow definition if the Package is added as Mandatory Package, and during task completion process if the task attachment is missing, user is expected to get this message in D2 client.
Please check weather the Task attachment is missing from repository in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Verify if the associated activity definition for the task (from process builder for example) has defined correctly the package/s.

or

2. Verify if the attached object (document/s or folder/s) to the task exists in repository or the user has at least BROWSE permission on it.

Also, a good idea is to check the D2 app server and JMS logs.